# Formatar parte do Textview em um evento

Tags: android

Fala galera, peço desculpas se a pergunta for repetida, mas é que procurei e não consegui resolver meu problema.

Preciso do seguinte: O usuário entra com uma String e o app devolve outra String igualzinha, porém se houver alguma sequência de caracteres repetida na palavra ele põe em negrito e de outra cor.

Ex: O usuario digita "Canjica" o app devolve "Canjica" porém com o primeiro "Ca" e o último "ca" em negrito e de outra cor, pois são sequências iguais.

Eu ja fiz o código pra reconhecer as sequências repetidos, já tenho a posição da primeira e da última sequência na string e ja tenho o tamanho delas.

Só que eu não sei como alterar o Textview em partes, deixando apenas algumas partes diferentes.

Será que alguém consegue me ajudar?? Valeu galeta

Answer (score 1):

Para fazer isso, você não precisa editar o TextView e sim inserir códigos nesse seu texto, usando o seguinte exemplo:

```
String sourceString = "<b>" + texto+ "</b> " + texto; 
mytextview.setText(Html.fromHtml(sourceString));
```

resultado

**texto** texto

ou Unicode characters

Comment: Aaah legal, então eu vou montando a String como eu quiser na hora do evento e só depois eu dou o .set no TextView?

Comment: Sim, ele vai renderizar como se fosse um elemento da web, usando Unicode characters não precisa colocar o Html dentro do setText.